# Windows defrag error Error code 0x89000019

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, defragment

Clean Install Windows 7 64bit, all updates applied

Ran defrag from the command prompt and got error Error code 0x89000019

Also logged w windows event error 257

Plenty of Free space.

What causes this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Delete all files inside the folder C:\Windows\Prefetch

Now defrag runs with no errors